# Adding instances into a different model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a notification app for my Django project.

I have this as one of my views:

```
class LikePostToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,pk):
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserPost,pk=pk)
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
                #Add notification to UserNotification model
                #Auto fill all fields
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

And this is my `UserNotification` model:

```
class UserNotification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('feed.UserPost',related_name='post-notification')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    notify_type = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

In the model I think I want the `user` field to be the user committing the action (Liking, commenting, etc.).

My question is how might I go above making it so that whenever someone likes a post or comments and therefore triggers the `LikePostToggle` view it also adds an instance to the `UserNotification` model so that the user can be notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance with `UserNotification()` then call save(), or you can use the `create` shortcut.

In the view you have access to the post and the logged in user. The timestamp will be added automatically and `read` will default to `False`, so you just have to decide what to set `notify_type` to:

```
obj.likes.add(user)
#Add notification to UserNotification model
notification = UserNotification.objects.create(
    user=self.request.user,
    post=obj,
    notify_type="???"
)
```

Comment: give me error `NameError at /feed/post/5/like/
name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: and doe not add instance to `UserNotification ` model upon post creation.

Comment: If it's a method in a class based view, it should be `self.request` not `request`.